# Can not unbox bigint to long

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

First of all pardon me for my english. I am getting this error__
When i try to explicitly convert object from executescalar() to long ,it gives can not unbox
executescalar() to long  .

while gives no error where converting to System.Decimal type.

```
long? id = (long?)ppwDb.ExecuteScalar(ppwDbCmd); //RAISE eXCEPTION
decimal? id = (decimal?)ppwDb.ExecuteScalar(ppwDbCmd);***// NO eXCEPTION
```

AND value of id is (id = 9874563) ,means under long range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to cast twice:

```
long? id = (long?) (decimal?) ppwDb.ExecuteScalar(ppwDbCmd);
```

The first cast will unbox the `decimal?`. The second cast will do a conversion from `decimal?` to `long?`. You cannot skip the first cast because a `decimal?` cannot be unboxed to a `long?`.

This assumes that `ppwDb.ExecuteScalar(ppwDbCmd)` returns `object` but the actual value returned is a `decimal?`.

However, I suspect that `ppwDb.ExecuteScalar(ppwDbCmd)` returns `DBNull.Value` if the id is null. In that case you will have to do special handling for that value:

```
object result = ppwDb.ExecuteScalar(ppwDbCmd);
long? id = result != DBNull.Value ? (long?) (decimal) result : null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
object retVal = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
long? Id = (retVal == DBNull.Value) ? null : Convert.ToInt64(retVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
object value = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar(ppwDbCmd);
long? l =  (value != null)?Convert.ToInt64(value):null;
```

above should work , use object instead of long? directly , you ma have null in the return the above statement check for null explicitly.

The reason is that the Value returned (as object ) is not a valid int ;
therefore, implicit cast don't work . if you say convert to int ,
you explicitly convert it to int truncating any double factor in the
returned number.

Comment: @IvanG 'if you have null in the return the above statement gives exception that you have to take care.' - You'll need to handle that situation.

Comment: If `selectCommand.ExecuteScalar()` returns null value, value returned by `Convert.ToInt64()` is going to be 0, that means you can't distinguish whether `selectCommand.ExecuteScalar()` returned 0 or null.